# How to use a faster loop than iterrows for the following code?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

I have a function that calculates the return of prices on a slice of the `return_df` dataframe and a separate loop that calculates standard deviations again on a sliced dataframe. I can run both and calculate the result right now with `iterrows` method. I have tried to apply the function to speed it up and even read about pandas/numpy vectorization but I get `nan` values instead. Is there a way to run this code faster? Any help is appreciated.

```
#sigma calculation function
def sigma_calculation(sample_trade):

    trade_index = sample_trade.index[0]
    sample_return_lst=[]
    eurusd_return_lst=[]
    for i, row in return_df[trade_index-28:trade_index:1].iterrows():
        sample_return_lst.append(return_df.iloc[i,0] * sample_trade.iloc[0,1])
        eurusd_return_lst.append(return_df.iloc[i,1] * sample_trade.iloc[0,1])

    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Asset Total Return'       : sample_return_lst,
     'Reference Total Return'   : eurusd_return_lst
     })  

    sigma_trade = stats_df['Asset Total Return'].std()
    sigma_eurusd = stats_df['Reference Total Return'].std()

    d_lev = sigma_trade/sigma_eurusd

    return d_lev

#running the sigma_calculation function for 45 rows from the return_df dataframe and creating a separate df from it
d_lev_lst = []
for i, row in return_df[4433::1].iterrows():
    d_lev_lst.append(sigma_calculation(return_df.iloc[[i]]))

d_lev_df = pd.DataFrame({'D-Leverage' : d_lev_lst})
```

This is what I tried for the second part (running sigma_calculation on 45 rows):

```
d_lev_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'D-Leverage'   : return_df['Asset Return'].iloc[4433::1].apply(lambda row: sigma_calculation(return_df.iloc[[row]])),
    })
```

Comment: In apply function by default `axis = 0` (which is columns).  Try specifying `axis = 1` to apply across rows.

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks, tried it the first time. I get a " TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' " error message

Comment: @edgemencandir--the error suggests you placed the axis argument in the wrong place causing it to mistake it as part of the lambda function definition when it should be an argument of apply.  However, I'm uncertain if this will work since sigma_calculation processes across several rows internally which I'm not sure if that's possible with apply.